# webcam - xawtv & mplayer

Tags: debian, camera, mplayer, v4l

Folks,

I am running through a weird problem. I am running Debian stretch on my thinkpad t430. When I try to capture video using my integrated webcam, I am able to view a streaming video, if I

```
xawtv -c /dev/video0
```

and not when I issue,

```
mplayer tv://
```

The error I get is,

```
--> mplayer tv://
MPlayer 1.3.0 (Debian), built with gcc-6.2.1 (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team
do_connect: could not connect to socket
connect: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing tv://.
TV file format detected.
Selected driver: v4l2
 name: Video 4 Linux 2 input
 author: Martin Olschewski <olschewski@zpr.uni-koeln.de>
 comment: first try, more to come ;-)
v4l2: your device driver does not support VIDIOC_G_STD ioctl, VIDIOC_G_PARM was used instead.
Selected device: Integrated Camera
 Capabilities:  video capture  streaming
 supported norms:
 inputs: 0 = Camera 1;
 Current input: 0
 Current format: YUYV
tv.c: norm_from_string(pal): Bogus norm parameter, setting default.
v4l2: ioctl enum norm failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Error: Cannot set norm!
Selected input hasn't got a tuner!
v4l2: ioctl set mute failed: Invalid argument
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.4
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [raw] RAW Uncompressed Video
Movie-Aspect is undefined - no prescaling applied.
VO: [vdpau] 640x480 => 640x480 Packed YUY2 
Selected video codec: [rawyuy2] vfm: raw (RAW YUY2)
==========================================================================
Audio: no sound
Starting playback...
v4l2: select timeout
libvdpau-va-gl: VideoSurface::PutBitsYCbCr_glsl(): not implemented source YCbCr format 'VDP_YCBCR_FORMAT_YUYV'
[vdpau] Error when calling vdp_video_surface_put_bits_y_cb_cr: VDP_STATUS_INVALID_Y_CB_CR_FORMAT


MPlayer interrupted by signal 11 in module: filter_video
- MPlayer crashed by bad usage of CPU/FPU/RAM.
  Recompile MPlayer with --enable-debug and make a 'gdb' backtrace and
  disassembly. Details in DOCS/HTML/en/bugreports_what.html#bugreports_crash.
 [ This binary of MPlayer in Debian is currently compiled with
   '--enable-debug'; the debugging symbols are in the package
   'mplayer-dbgsym'.]
```

Could anyone shed some light on why mplayer crashes with the above error, whereas xawtv able to show?

Any help to debug and fix the issue would be much appreciated.

I have **video 4 linux 2 (v4l2)** installed and running default kernel comes with debian stretch and updated to the latest through `apt`

My `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` says:

```
Integrated Camera (usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6):
/dev/video0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aah!

The issue has vanished with

```
primusrun mplayer tv://
```

As far my understanding goes, the mplayer must be requiring NVIDIA card installed on my laptop, alongside integrated intel graphics. My issue now is making it work with opencv!.

Anyway, thanks to those who have paid attention and made efforts to address/attempt to help me.